# Is it possible to do getProgramAccounts using ProgramTestContext?

Tags: testing, solana-test-validator, solana-program-test

I am trying to speed up my tests by switching from using a local test validator to using `ProgramTestContext`.
This will let me execute multiple tests in parallel where each one has its own instance of `ProgramTestContext`.
While I was rewriting the tests to use `ProgramTestContext`, I noticed that there is no way to call `getProgramAccounts`. I searched Solana Rust docs and the API docs in docs.rs to no avail.

Is it not possible to do `getProgramAccounts` when testing without using a local validator?

Comment: You're correct that the `BanksClient` exposed by `ProgramTestContext` doesn't allow you to call `get_program_accounts`.  You'll have to fetch the accounts one by one, or put in a PR to `BanksClient` to implement `get_program_accounts`.

Answer (score -1):

yes it is possible to get accounts that are associated with a program, I would say the ProgramTestContext is a tool on the Solana SDK that allows you to test smart contracts in a Test Environment...so to get the associated accounts you can use the `get_program_accounts` function.

Comment: I can't find `get_program_accounts` impl'd on the `ProgramTestContext` or `BanksClient` (`ProgramTestContext.client`). I tried looking in docs.rs